# Using a vector inside a function as argument

Tags: r, function, vector, arguments

I use a function called mplusObject and rather than including a filename as an argument, I want to be able to run a loop with this code and let the filename be entered automatically by R (see VECTOR_1 towards the end of the code). This is a short and simplified version of the code:

```
mymodel <- mplusObject(
TITLE = "Some analysis;",
VARIABLE = "
  usevariables = x1 x2 x3 c_age c_agesq;",
MODEL = "
  att BY x1 x2 x3;
  att ON c_age c_agesq;",
SAVEDATA = "
  save = fscores; 
  file = VECTOR_1;",
  rdata = selectedgroup)
```

The function mplusObject (in the package MplusAutomation) has several arguments, including one where it gives a filename for saving data generated by the model (towards the end of the code above). Instead of the filename, I have now written VECTOR_1.

I would like to define the content of `VECTOR_1 (VECTOR_1 <- "filename")` outside the function. Coming from Stata, I thought this would be easy (by using something similar to what Stata calls local macros). But I don't succeed with R. How do I show R that `VECTOR_1` is a vector and shouldn't be taken as the actual argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your filepaths in a vector with

```
myvector <- c("filepath1", "filepath2", ...)
```

and loop over it with `lapply` to save all your outputs in a list:

```
mymodels <- lapply(myvector, function(x) mplusObject(all other fixed arguments, file = x))
```

Comment: Thanks @Leo P.! I use a simple numbering up to 30, "filename_1" ... "filename_30". 
Can I use something like this, with i going fom 1 to 30: `myvector <- paste("~/filename",i,sep="")`?

Comment: try `myvector <- paste0("~/filename_", 1:30)` for "filename_1" to "filename_30"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this out later. If it works, I'll indicate that it solved my problem.